# How to import BitmapTextureAtlas in AndEngine in android

Tags: android, andengine

I am new in AndEngine. I have import the andEngine.jar file in eclipse. But when i use BitmapTextureAtlas class then my eclipse unable to import this class. How can i import this class? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using a wrong version of AndEngine, the method of importing .jar file is no longer used. For the latest version, see http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html